# Arrows on 2D streamlines in paraview

Tags: paraview

I have created a slice. On this slice I have generated 2D streamlines. I would like to have arrows to represent the direction of the streamlines in the following manner:
[image]

I tried to create them using Glyphs. Below is the screenshot of the settings I used in the Glyph filter:

[image]

I am getting the following as the output:

[image]

As one can see the arrows are not in line with the streamlines. Can someone please help me get the desired output? Also I just want the arrow head and not the arrow itself.

When I use the edge arrow I am getting the following (Please note that I have rotated the slice to show that the arrow head is appearing perpendicular to the streamlines):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `orientation array` to the array used to extract the streamlines.

Use `EdgeArrow` as Glyph type to only have the arrow head.

*Edit: investigation*

1. Check the `Glyph Transform' values. Rotation should be [0,0,0].
2. You can also use the Spreadsheet View to check the values of the orientation array at the buggy points.
3. Here is a state file I made with PV 5.8 RC1, so you can compare with your configurations.
   It contains: a Wavelet source to create a grid, a RandomAttributes filter to add Points Vector, a StreamTracer and finally the Glyph filter: 
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/11E3du4warRIX5v8pxX7LxdCy-jsmGlZ5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ Nico Vuaille I did what you suggested. But now the arrow head is perpendicular to the streamlines.

Comment: I have posted an image of what I am getting in the question section.

Comment: can you share a minimal example ? (data / pvsm) ?

Comment: I am sorry as I am not allowed to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out the source of error. I have the 2D streamlines on a slice which is perpendicular to the flow. Hence when I choose the orientation array as the mean velocity, the arrow heads were appearing perpendicular. Now I need to rotate them accordingly to fix this.